# Laravel Entrust Different Roles on Different Organizations

Tags: php, laravel-5, roles, entrust

Is it possible to have different roles on different organizations for a user using Entrust https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust

Entrust docs say you can have a user and attach roles to it. But what I would like is a user can belong to multiple organisations and has roles for each organisation

Something like this

- John Doe

  - Organisation A

    - Admin
  - Organisation B

    - User

I'm also using Laravel

Comment: did you find any solution?